# Java is sorting my array of doubles by itself. Why?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, double

I was trying to create a merge sort for a class and stumbled upon this. For some reason when I split the original array into to smaller arrays, it sorts the contents from smallest to largest. So, all I had to do was put them back together to end up with the result I wanted. I looked everywhere I could think of and couldn't find any explanation for the behavior. No amount of googling gave me any answers.

The contents of the original array are doubles generated with Math.random().

Here is the relevant code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.*;


public class Sorting
{
private static int n = 10;
private static double[] arrOne = null;
private static double[] arrTwo = null;
private static boolean timedOut = false;
private static boolean bubbleTimeOut = false;
private static boolean mergeTimeOut = false;
private static long startTime = 0;
private static long endTime = 0;
private static long bubbleSortTime = 0;
private static long mergeSortTime = 0;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        while(!(timedOut))
        {
            arrOne = fillArray();
            arrTwo = arrOne;

            if(bubbleTimeOut==false)
            {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                bubbleSort();
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                bubbleSortTime = endTime-startTime;
                System.out.println("Bubble sort with "+n+" items takes "+bubbleSortTime+"ms.");
            }

            if(mergeTimeOut==false)
            {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                arrTwo = mergeSort(arrTwo);
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                mergeSortTime = endTime-startTime;
                System.out.println("Merge sort with "+n+" items takes "+mergeSortTime+"ms.");
            }

            if(bubbleTimeOut && mergeTimeOut)
            {
                timedOut = true;
            }

            n = n*10;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Java ran out of memory.");
    }
}

public static double[] mergeSort(double[] arr)
{
    if(arr.length<=1)
    {
        return arr;
    }
    int middle = arr.length/2;
    int left = middle;
    int right = arr.length - left;
    double[] tempOne = new double[left];
    double[] tempTwo = new double[right];

    //put first half into an array
    for(int i=0; i<left; i++)
    {
        tempOne[i] = arr[i];
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(endTime-startTime>20000)
        {
            mergeTimeOut = true;
            return arr;
        }
    }
    //put second half into an array
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i=left;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        tempTwo[temp] = arr[i];
        temp++;
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(endTime-startTime>20000)
        {
            mergeTimeOut = true;
            return arr;
        }
    }

    int ph = tempOne.length + tempTwo.length;
    double[] tempThree = new double[ph];
    for(int i=0;i<tempOne.length;i++)
    {
        tempThree[i] = tempOne[i];
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(endTime-startTime>20000)
        {
            mergeTimeOut = true;
            return arr;
        }
    }
    int k = tempOne.length;
    for(int i=0; i<tempTwo.length;i++)
    {
        tempThree[k] = tempTwo[i];  
        k++;
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(endTime-startTime>20000)
        {
            mergeTimeOut = true;
            return arr;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

public static void bubbleSort()
{
    double ph = 0;
    boolean swapped = true;
    while(swapped)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for(int i=n-1; i>0; i--)
        {
            if(arrOne[i] < arrOne[i-1])
            {
                ph = arrOne[i];
                arrOne[i] = arrOne[i-1];
                arrOne[i-1] = ph;
                swapped = true;
            }
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(endTime-startTime>20000)
            {
                swapped = false;
                bubbleTimeOut = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

//this method is just to help me test my code.
public static void printArray(double[] arr)
{
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}

public static double[] fillArray()
{
    double[] arr = new double[n];
    double rand = 0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        rand = Math.random();
        arr[i] = rand;
    }
    return arr;
}
}
```

So, if the contents of the original were {8,5,4,7,3,1,2,6}, then after I split it in half and put it back together I would get {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} without me having to actually sort anything.

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://ideone.com/sobNAU) You're doing something weird somewhere we can't see.

Comment: I went ahead an added the complete code. If something is weird, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: You do realize that you're offering a presorted array to mergeSort due to `arrTwo=arrOne`?

Comment: Also, the abundant usage of globals makes the code fragile and hard to read, eg how startTime and endTime are being used, it can be solved entirely locally.

Comment: Do you understand that when you do `arrOne = fillArray(); arrTwo = arrOne;` you have only ONE array, with two different references pointing to the SAME array?  So after the bubble sort you are passing a sorted array (using a different reference) to the merge sort.  Go back and examine your code for every place you assumed you were creating a new array but were not.

Comment: You're right, I did not realize that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble starts here:

```
arrOne = fillArray();
arrTwo = arrOne;
```

This makes arrTwo just an "alias" of arrOne, ie another name to reference the same data with. To avoid that, you have to **copy** the array if you actually want them to be 2 individual arrays with the same content, eg by using

```
arrOne = fillArray();
arrTwo = Arrays.copyOf(arrOne,arrOne.length);
```

or, of course, by doing it manually with a `for` loop if you cannot use Arrays.